# Difference between "too long" and "for too long"

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference between "too long" and "for too long"

For example the ones below

You can't stay under water for too long 
Or 
You can't stay under water too long

Do not have that candy in your mouth for too long 
Or 
Do not have that candy in your mouth too long

Comment: In that circumstance, there is no difference at all.

Please do not take that to apply to any other circumstance,

Comment: _For_ is deletable for any noun phrase object indicating a duration. _He stayed under water (for) 20 minutes/his whole life/quite a while/no longer than he had to_.

Comment: I can't stay under water for too long. I'll drown.  However, the low gravity pleasure means that I can't stay under water too long. I'll dive down over and over, within the boundaries of that darn first sentence. Two different meanings. -- Second pair of sentences the for seems to add nothing useful. The 'for' can, depending on the sentence, imply consequences, or not.